# Explicit form for operators representing the integrals of motion in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, symmetry

Is there any way to derive the quantum mechanical operators that form the [integrals of motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176511/) in quantum mechanics from the Hamiltonian for general systems?

Let's for simplicity focus on stationary problems.

For example if I have a system with a(n obvious) continuous spatial symmetry, like the electron in the potential of the proton with its apparent $SO(3)$ symmetry (neglecting now the 'hidden' Runge-Lenz vector conservation) and the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_0$, and I perturb the potential e.g. by adding a second proton to the potential $\hat{V}'$. Since the number degrees of freedom remain unchanged, we have as many constants of motion as in the $SO(3)$ symmetric case, with the same number of integrals of motion for time independent problems. But for the $SO(3)$ case we knew that the total orbital angular momentum $\hat{L}^2$ and one of its components $\hat{L}_z$ were integrals of motion, which were induced by the Noether principle by the continuous $SO(3)$ symmetry. My question is now: What are the two new quantities that are conserved in stationary states of the system described by the Hamiltonian: $\hat{H}_0+\hat{V}'$?

Is there a way to determine any* representation of these operators (that commute with the Hamiltonian) in explicit form?

On a more concrete basis if we consider the [particle in a ring of radius $R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring) there we have the Schrödinger equation:

\begin{align} \hat{H}_0 \psi & = E \psi\\
\hat{H}_0  & = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2R^2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \vartheta^2} 
\end{align}

for $0\le \vartheta < 2 \pi$ with the eigenfunctions
$$ \psi_{ml}(\vartheta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{iml\theta} $$
for $m\in\{-1,1\}$ and $l\in \mathbb{N^+_0}$ and the corresponding energies
$$ E_{l} =\frac{l^2 \hbar^2}{2R^2m}.$$

Since the system has a continuous rotational symmetry we have conservation of angular momentum $L_z$ with the corresponding angular momentum operator

$$\hat{L}_z = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} $$

As obviously

$$ [\hat{H}_0,\hat L_z] = 0 $$

angular momentum is conserved in all solutions of the stationary problem. Now lets suppose we break the symmetry by adding a small attractive $\delta$ function potential of "height" $\epsilon$ at $\vartheta_0 = 0$

$$ [\hat{H}_0 - \epsilon \delta(\vartheta)] \psi = E \psi $$

This system has exactly one bound state (i.e. one state with  $E<0$)

$$ \psi_b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \left(e^{d \vartheta} + e^{-d(\vartheta - 2\pi)}\right) $$

With the some $d>0$ (on a side note: which is determined by $ \coth(\pi d) = \frac{2\pi \hbar^2}{ \epsilon e m R} d $)

My question instantiated for this system is basically if there exists a non-trivial operator $\hat{\Lambda}_\epsilon$ with

$$ [\hat{H}_0 - \epsilon \delta(\theta) ,\hat \Lambda_\epsilon] = 0 $$ and

$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \Lambda_\epsilon = \hat{L}_z $$

and how it can be determined.

---

*) I understand that the quantities are not unique because any "algebraic combination" will be another representative

Comment: This post (v5) seems _too broad._ Perhaps it is better to focus on your specific example.

Comment: I could extend the question slightly and give an even simpler specific example. But maybe its better to wait for more opinions?

Comment: For what it's worth, the number of globally defined COMs/IOMs is not necessarily preserved under deformation of the potential even if the number of DOF remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you that was a good point. I tried to correct this.

Comment: There is a suggested edit to this post, but seem not be able to approve it :"You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits." So what to do?

Comment: There is not a suggested edit in this thread at this moment.