# Whence the $i$ in QM Poisson bracket definition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, commutator, complex-numbers, poisson-brackets

On p. 87 of Dirac's *Quantum Mechanics* he introduces the quantum analog of the classical Poisson bracket$^1$

$$ [u,v]~=~\sum_r \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial q_r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial p_r}- \frac{\partial u}{\partial p_r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial q_r}\right)    \tag{1}$$

as

$$uv-vu ~=~i~\hbar~[u,v]. \tag{7}$$

I'm not worried about the $\hbar$ but if there is an (alternative) explanation of why the introduction of $i$ is unavoidable that might help.

---

$^1$ Note that Dirac uses square brackets to denote the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket).

Comment: Note that "QM Poisson bracket" is not a term that is in use today. The symbol $[u,v]$ is called a commutator, and while it *is* connected to the Poisson brackets of hamiltonian mechanics (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/) for the connection, and also possibly [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130800/)), no one calls it a Poisson bracket because it isn't really one.

Comment: OK, I'll bite--why the downvote? There are two upvoted answers with +2 and +3. Can the question have been so devoid of interest? Really?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The imaginary unit $i$ is there to turn quantum observables/selfadjoint operators into anti-selfadjoint operators, so that they form a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) wrt. the commutator.

Or equivalently, consider the Lie algebra of quantum observables/selfadjoint operators with the commutator divided with $i$ as Lie bracket.

The latter Lie algebra corresponds in turn to the Poisson algebra of classical functions, cf. the [correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).

Answer (score 3):

Is it unavoidable: No.

Is it convenient: Yes.

Why: because given two hermitian operators $A,B$, their commutator is anti-hermitian.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if it explained why it's convenient to turn the anti-hermitian thing into a hermitian thing.

Comment: @DanielSank yep.