# QCD Conjugate Variable Determination

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-chromodynamics, commutator, yang-mills

This is not homework question.  I have not been in school for over 40 years.

Are there conjugate variables in QCD?  How are they determined?

I can relate to Heisenberg uncertainty in QM as the metrics are sufficiently close to classical.  But for QCD, I am at a loss as there is little relation to classical.  I would like to know how to looks for this information.  Web searches have turned up nothing.

Comment: Try Hamiltonian quantization of QCD, canonical conjugate variables. eg http://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03875 eqn 77

Comment: Mitchell,  This is just what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Mitchell,   Additionally, I found another thread that was very helpful on this site as What is the Physical Meaning of Commutation of Two Operators?   https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9199