# What does it "physically" mean, in terms of uncertainty and measurements, for a commutator to be different than zero in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Let's consider the commutator $[L_i,L_j] = i \hbar L_k$ of the angular momentum. The consequence of this equation is that two components of the angular momentum cannot be simultaneously measured. I would like to know why exactly this physical interpretation follows from the equation.

Comment: I think Grant Sanderson of 3b1b also asked a similar question some time ago. Here's the link to his tweet. Might be helpful.

https://twitter.com/3blue1brown/status/1288881356332662790

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What is the physical meaning of commutators in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130800/2451), [What is the Physical Meaning of Commutation of Two Operators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9194/2451) and links therein.